# Loading and viewing data JSON data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I"m learning d3.js and in doing so I'm trying to load a csv successfully before making visualizations. This is what I have so far.
    
    
      
        
        Testing Pie Chart
       </script>-->

```
d3.csv("C:/Users/ZKYMME/Desktop/csv_test.csv", function(data) { 
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.T1 = +d.T1;
    d.T2 = +d.T2;
    d.T3 = +d.T3;
    d.T4 = +d.T4;
    d.T5 = +d.T5;
  });
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

How can I check to make sure that the data has correctly 'loaded' or that it's ready for use?

Comment: There are lot of ways to do that, you can debug and check the parameters. Console.log is another way to do so and also you can go for request callback in documentation https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#request :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 has callback for csv request, which can be used for error handling.

```
d3.csv("../path.csv", function(d) {
  return d;
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(error, rows);
});
```

Your code will look like this,

```
d3.csv("C:/Users/ZKYMME/Desktop/csv_test.csv", function(data) { 
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.T1 = +d.T1;
    d.T2 = +d.T2;
    d.T3 = +d.T3;
    d.T4 = +d.T4;
    d.T5 = +d.T5;
  });
  console.log(data[0]);
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(error, rows)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As in the [documentation specified](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv), d3.csv returns a [request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#request), which you can use to do error handling.